# R—Plotting the number of points that overlap rather than a symbol

Tags: r, plot, overlap

I am doing a plot where there are overlapping values because both x and y are discrete. I have searched and found examples where they make the area of the dot proportional to the number of data points that overlap at a single x-y point, but what I'd like to be able to do is to plot the **number** of points that overlap. So, for example, if the point (5, 7) were repeated 7 times, I'd like it to plot the number "7" at that point rather than a symbol. I feel like this should be possible but can't figure out how to do it.

Here is some code that generates the plot I am hoping to do this for:

> worker <- 1:10
>
> defects <- t(matrix(rbinom(200, 100, 0.1),  ncol=10))
>
> matplot(worker, defects)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Why dont you just count the nummer of duplicates in a seperate column and use this as the symbol. Just remove all the duplicates and you can plot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You need to get the "count" of observations for each x,y pair and then you can use annotation to get your plot. Here's an example using `data.table` and `ggplot2`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# using a sample dataset 
dat <- as.data.table(mtcars)

# creating a variable called "count" for no. of overlaps for a given (gear,carb) pair 
ggplot(dat[, .(count = .N), by = .(gear, carb)]) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = gear, y= carb, label = count) )
```

[image]

You can format the text any way you want (font, size etc.) or combined with other items e.g. add `geom_point` so you see a point along with the text - you can set the transparency or size based on the number of overlapping points (`count` in this example).

```
# Using nudge_x, nudge_y to avoid marker and text overlap
ggplot(dat[, .(count = .N), by = .(gear, carb)]) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = gear, y= carb, label = count), nudge_x = 0.05, nudge_y = 0.05) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = gear, y = carb), color = 'dark red')
```

[image]

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: SUPER helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice, please "accept" the answer if it works for you - so it is marked as solved.

Comment: Did I just need to upvote it or is there something else? I don't see an "accept" button. sorry, new to the site. Thanks!

Comment: @HaroldBuck you should see a check-mark under the upvote button, read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you! Much appreicated.